# How to use Gmail for POP from Office 365 when there are too many messages?

Tags: gmail, office-365, pop3

I have an email account in Office 365 that I want to transfer into my Gmail account. Unfortunately, the only way to do it would be to use POP (it doesn't seem like Gmail in the web interface allows to download mail using IMAP) and the problem is that there are many emails on the account.

I get the error:

> Error: Too many messages to download

I don't want to transfer all messages anyway, just the ones from a certain date, but I just don't know how to do that in Gmail or if it is possible. Is my only solution to delete email on the POP server? I would rather not do that.

Just to perhaps help, the POP server is an Office 365 account, so maybe there is another workaround to forward email from this service to my Gmail account.

Comment: *"I have an email account I want to download email from into my Gmail account"* So you actually want to **transfer a group of emails from your Office account to Gmail**. If not, please clarify.

Comment: yes, exactly. all my emails from the Office account, preferably keeping them in the Office account.

Comment: In this case, *"I don't want to download all messages anyway, just the ones from a certain date"* applies to Office and not Gmail. There are tools for that. Have you tried the Office forums?

Comment: BTW, how many messages are we talking about? There might be a work-around.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a desktop email client like Outlook.

For already received emails, configure Outlook to connect to both accounts by using IMAP, the "move" or "copy" the messages from one account to the other.

For new messages configure your Office 365 account to forward the new incoming messages to you email account.